# SSH forwarding with Spring Cloud Config inside Docker

Tags: docker, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have a Spring Boot application set up to be a Spring Cloud Config server, and to pull the configuration from a Gitlab repository specified in the application.yml for the Spring Boot app. I'm using a deploy key on the Gitlab server.

This works running locally with the private key for the deploy key in my ~/.ssh directory.

I would like to run this app in Docker, and I want to use SSH forwarding instead of storing the private key from ~/.ssh in the Docker container.

I have installed ssh-agent on the Docker host and configured the following for the container in my docker-compose.yml:

```
volumes:
      - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent
environment:
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent
```

I have a config file in ~/.ssh with the following:

```
Host mygitlabserver.com
      Hostname mygitlabserver.com
      StrictHostKeyChecking no
      ForwardAgent yes
```

This all works if I SSH into the running Docker container and run a Git clone manually. But if I start the Spring Boot app in the container and try to pull configuration from Spring Cloud Config, I get this error in the Spring Boot apps logs:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot clone or checkout repository] with root cause com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect
```

If I add the private key in ~/.ssh inside the Docker container instead of trying to use forwarding, the app is able to pull configuration from Git. Is there a way to get Spring Cloud Config to work inside Docker with the SSH forwarding?

If not, is there some other way to avoid storing the private key in ~/.ssh on the file system in the running Docker container?